# How do I make an image float across my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a .gif (transparency) that I want to appear on the left side of the web browser, float across the entire browser face and disappear on the right hand side.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI: That [tag:java] tag should be a [tag:javascript] tag. There's a huge difference between the two languages, and if you want to get the right help from the right people, you will want to be careful with your tags. I've made the change for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move an image across a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621259/move-an-image-across-a-web-page)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to float the image to the left. But what do you mean by "face and disappear on the right hand side"?

Answer (score 1):

you should use jquery animate function like

```
.img{position:absolute;left:0}
$('.img').animate({"left":"100%"},300,function(){$('.img').delay(300).fadeOut()})
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked. I found it with a simple google search.
[Move an image across a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621259/move-an-image-across-a-web-page)